# How to use QTimer to view a image sequence?

Tags: qt

In the program, I am trying to create a image player using QT. When I click a button in the UI, the program will create a image slideshow with a 2s pause. I tried to use the QTimer to such things, but failed to do so. Hence, I want to ask how to achieve my purpose by using QTimer.

Let me describe the flow of my program. When the user click a button in the main window, the sub-window showpic will be opened and then start showing each image for a pause of 2s in its qgraphsview. The images filepath are stored in the "QStringlist filenames".

---

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include "showpic.h"
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QTimer>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void display(const QString & , ShowPic* );


private slots:
    void tick();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QFileSystemModel *model;
    QString filesPath;
    ShowPic *showpic;
    QStringList filenames;
    QStringList::const_iterator m_imageIt;
    QTimer m_timer;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

showpic.h

```
#ifndef SHOWPIC_H
#define SHOWPIC_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class ShowPic;
}

class ShowPic : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ShowPic(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ShowPic();

private:
    Ui::ShowPic *ui;    

public:
    void addPixmap(const QPixmap &pixmap);
};



#endif // SHOWPIC_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<QFileDialog>
#include<QFileSystemModel>
#include<QStringList>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QTime>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTimer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    filenames.append("C:\\test\\image.jpg");
    filenames.append("C:\\test\\apple.jpg");
    filenames.append("C:\\test\\orange.jpg");
    filenames.append("C:\\test\\lemon.jpg");
    filenames.append("C:\\test\\grape.jpg");
    m_imageIt = filenames.begin();

    m_timer.setInterval(5000);
    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tick()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::display(const QString & filename, ShowPic* showpic) {
    showpic->addPixmap(filename);
}

void MainWindow::tick(){
    showpic = new ShowPic();
    showpic->show();
    display(*m_imageIt, showpic);
    m_imageIt ++;
}

/*
void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
        if (ev->timerId() == m_timer.timerId()) tick();
}*/

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    /*showpic = new ShowPic();
    QPixmap pixmap("C:\\test\\image.jpg");
    showpic->addPixmap(pixmap);
    showpic->show();*/

    m_timer.start();
}
```

showpic.cpp

```
#include "showpic.h"
#include "ui_showpic.h"
#include <QThread>

ShowPic::ShowPic(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ShowPic)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene);
}

ShowPic::~ShowPic()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ShowPic::addPixmap(const QPixmap &pixmap){
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addPixmap(pixmap);
}
```

The compiling message error:

[image]

Comment: You speak of a Timer, but I do not see that you use it, it shows how you are using it even if it does not work

Comment: I have tried to use QBasicTimer, but the code is failed to compile, so I delete them.

Comment: Place it even if it does not work, if at the moment of compiling you generate an error then attach that message to your post.

Comment: the slot on_pushButton_clicked is responsible for placing an image in QGraphicsView, do you still want to add an image with the button?

Comment: I have changed to the erroneous one. For your question, yes, I think it is still suitable to be used. The button has two function now, adding an image and playing the images sequence.

Comment: What I understand from your post is that you want to change the QPixmap every 2 seconds. I am right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @md612 You need to read *and understand* [mcve] and [ask] ASAP, and best start with taking the tour. Posting verbose, untrimmed code while failing to provide a basic description of the problematic behaviour is frowned upon around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the timer, it is because you forgot to declare `display()`, `tick()`, and `timerEvent()` as part of the `MainWindow::` class, so they cannot access `MainWindow` members.

The timer should be even easier to use than your code. First I recommend you use a `QTimer` instead of `QBasicTimer`.  Then you can simply connect to its `timeout()` signal.

mainwindow.h

```
#include <QTimer>

QTimer m_timer;
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ...
    m_imageIt = filenames.begin();

    m_timer.setInterval(5000);
    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tick()));
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    m_timer.start();
}
```

You do not need `timerEvent()` function at all.

Comment: `connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tick()));` or `connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tick()));`

Comment: The latter. Good catch... fixed.   
Or with Qt5 syntax:`connect(&m_timer, QTimer::timeout, this, MainWindow::tick);`

Comment: It is always advisable to use the new syntax, the previous syntax can hide errors. :P

Comment: Sorry, the present code doesn't show the sub-window. I have updated the code according to your suggestion. Please help. By the way, I think the timer doesn't stop when it shows the last image.

Comment: What do you still need help with? Your code looks OK as far as the timer kicking off `tick()` every 5s.  And no, the timer doesn't stop automagically when you run out of images... you have to call `m_timer.stop();` yourself.